# sharepoint keywords not supported 'cube'

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

Was creating a report data source in SharePoint PowerPivot site. Below is my connection string and the error when i try Test connection

> data source = sp13; initial catalog = MultidimensionalProject1; cube =
>   'Internet Sales'

I also try

> data source = sp13; initial catalog = MultidimensionalProject1**-ee**;
>   cube = 'Internet Sales'

And get the Error

> Keyword not supported: 'cube'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set data source type to **Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services**.